Python Tkinter: Change button position based on window size
This is just a concept that I haven't actually programmed yet. I'm still learning the logic for Tkinter and I'm wondering how to Change button position based on the window size. The best thing I can compare my idea in my head is something similar to word wrap.
Original size:
-------------------------------
|  -----    -----    -----    |
| |     |  |     |  |     |   |
| |     |  |     |  |     |   |
|  -----    -----    -----    |
|  -----    -----             |
| |     |  |     |            |
| |     |  |     |            |
|  -----    -----             |
-------------------------------

Change Example 1:
--------------------
|  -----    -----  |
| |     |  |     | |
| |     |  |     | |
|  -----    -----  |
|  -----    -----  |
| |     |  |     | |
| |     |  |     | |
|  -----    -----  |
|  -----           |
| |     |          |
| |     |          |
|  -----           |
--------------------

Change Example 2:
-----------------------------------------------
|  -----    -----    -----    -----    -----  |
| |     |  |     |  |     |  |     |  |     | |
| |     |  |     |  |     |  |     |  |     | |
|  -----    -----    -----    -----    -----  |
-----------------------------------------------

Is there a way to do something like this?

the answers to this question show how you can detect a resize in the window. using the new width, you can compute and change the positions of the buttons and set the height of the window. I suggest to put your button instances into a list, so you can iterate over them

You can put those buttons inside a Text widget with wrap enabled.
Below is a simple example:
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

box = tk.Text(root, wrap="char")
box.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

for i in range(5):
    btn = tk.Button(box, text=f"Button {i+1}", width=10, height=5)
    box.window_create("end", window=btn, pady=5, padx=5)

root.mainloop()





This works but I also find that it's possible to delete the buttons
This flaw might cause problems, so do you know how to fix it?

Nvm I got it, thanks for your help!
